# Converting curl command to python

Tags: python, bash, curl

I am new to Python. I am trying to convert below bash script command to Python using subprocess. I don't get any output nor do I see any failure when I execute my Python script.

This is the bash command that needs to be ported to Python.

```
curl -u 'lawn:oldlawn!' -k -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET 'https://192.168.135.20:443/api/json/v2/types/dev-objs/1'
```

My python code:

```
get_curl():
  curl = """curl -u 'lawn:oldlawn!' -k -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET 'https://192.168.135.20:443/api/json/v2/types/dev-objs/1'"""

  args = curl.split()

  process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

  stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
  print stdout
  print stderr

# End of python code
```

After I execute `get_curl()`, `print stdout` and `print stderr` does not print anything though `dev-objs/1` exists.

When I execute the same command as bash command it works and I see the REST API output.

Can anyone help me what may be going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: to convert string to list of arguments try shlex.split, not str.split.

Comment: Just curious; is there a reason why you would want to execute `curl` instead of using `urllib`?

Comment: bash is awful and subprocess is not great either. Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) library instead of `curl` (and instead of `urllib` too).

Comment: @AlexHall: Whyever would you recommend an external, third-party library for such simple HTTP calls when `urllib` is built in?

Comment: @Dolda2000 because requests makes it ridiculously simple. You *can* use `urllib`, but... you shouldn't (unless you have to)

Comment: @AlexHall: `urllib` is really quite simple too, and there's nothing wrong with using it directly. Introducing extraneous dependencies for such simple things bothers me quite a bit.

Comment: @Dolda2000 https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705

Comment: @AlexHall: There is no way that is worth installing external dependencies for. If anything, I could argue for constructing the `Authorization` header manually with `binascii`, which would be simpler than using a `HTTPBasicAuthHandler`, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}


import requests

proxies = {
  'https': 'https://lawn:oldlawn!@192.168.135.20:443',
}

req = requests.get('https:...', proxies=proxies, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

I don't think there is a -s flag for requests as no data will be output unless you print what is returned with *req.json()*.

I thought you had a capital `U` not a `u` so all you really need is to do is to use  [basic-authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) passing `auth = (user, pass)`, set `verify=False` as per [Brendans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424657/2141635).

Why your *subprocess* code did not work was because you have some args quoted like `"'lawn:oldlawn!'"`, what you want is:

```
args = ['curl',
 '-u',
 'lawn:oldlawn!',
 '-k',
 '-s',
 '-H',
 'Content-Type: application/json',
 '-X',
 'GET',
 'https://192.168.135.20:443/api/json/v2/types/dev-objs/1']

process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False,   stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Comment: I was looking for the requests syntax, and when I came back you had posted this :P (also note, that it's probably better to [set up the SSL cert](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) as the CA root or something rather than forget about verification)

Comment: What is the purpose of using the proxy?

Comment: @WayneWerner, yep that would definitely be a better approach, the OP used  -k so I just replicated.

Comment: Natch :) I just wanted to offer that bit of enhancement for anyone who comes looking. I'm not even sure if curl can do that. Or maybe just stay lazy and use `verify=False` myself :P

Answer (score 1):

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) will make your http(s) requests far simpler:

```
import requests


response = requests.get('https://192.168.135.20:443/api/json/v2/types/dev-objs/1', 
                        verify=False, auth=('lawn', 'oldlawn!'))
print response.json()
```

Comment: You need a `verify=False` on here

Comment: Thank you all, using shelx.split() resolved my issue.

Comment: Next I will convert this to use request library rather than subprocess.